# required width and height image php prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

there is a way to force upload with specific width and height in php upload , i have this module

```
       if(Configuration::get('SHOW_IMAGES') == 1) {

            $images = count($_FILES['images']['name']);
            if ($images <= Configuration::get('MAX_IMAGES')) {
                for ($i=1; $i<=Configuration::get('MAX_IMAGES'); $i++) {
                    if ($_FILES['images']['name'][$i] != "") {
                        if ((($_FILES['images']['type'][$i] == "image/pjpeg") || 
                                ($_FILES['images']['type'][$i] == "image/jpeg") || 
                                ($_FILES['images']['type'][$i] == "image/png")) &&
                                ($_FILES['images']['size'][$i] < $this->return_bytes(ini_get('post_max_size')))) {
                            $url_images[$i] = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i];
                        }
                        else {
                            $this->errors[] = $this->module->l('The image format is incorrect or max size to upload is', 'addproduct').' '.ini_get('post_max_size');
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $this->errors[] = $this->module->l('The image  is incorrect or max size to upload is', 'addproduct');
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                $this->errors[] = $this->module->l('The maxim images to upload is', 'addproduct').' '.Configuration::get('MAX_IMAGES');
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use getimagesize it will provide height and width

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($file["tmp_name"]);    
if ($width == $minwidth  && $height == $minheight) 
{
    echo "success";    
}else
{
    echo "error";               
}
```

getimagesize() is php per-defined function. this will determine the size of any given image file and return the dimensions along with the file type and a height/width.for more info.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php